# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve when install a published react component libary which using rollup to build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, es6-modules, rollup

I create a react component library named '@b/b-core', and using Rollup to build and publish to the repository. I install the libary in a react app, It shows `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@b/b-core'` when use `npm start`, But there is no errors in the component's source code of react app in vs code using import statement, It seems types are correct.

Here is the `rollup.config.js`

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default [
    {
        input: "src/index.ts",
        output: [
            {
                file: packageJson.main,
                format: "cjs",
                sourcemap: true,
            },
            {
                file: packageJson.module,
                format: "esm",
                sourcemap: true,
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            peerDepsExternal(),
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
            copy({
                targets: [
                    { src: 'package.json', dest: 'dist' },
                ],
            }),
        ],
        external: ["react", "react-dom"],
    },
    {
        input: "src/index.ts",
        output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "es" }],
        plugins: [dts()],
    },
];
```

Here is the `packages.json`, I add main,module,types and peerDependencies

```
{
  "name": "@b/b-core",
  "version": "0.1.6",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "esprima": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.19",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.2",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/esprima": "^4.0.3",
    "rollup": "^2.79.1",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^5.3.1",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0"
  }
}
```

I am new to the rollup and react, I did it fllowed https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-component-library-react-typescript/

Comment: The example in the repository that is linked to that blog is not correct. Specifically, `export * from "m";` does not reexport the `default` export of `"m"`. To reexport the default one needs to write `

Comment: Also, if you look at the comments everyone's complaining about it: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-component-library-react-typescript/#comment-9614. Reexport the default with `export {default as Button} from "./button";` etc.

Comment: @Aluan I update the question, I export BPageServiceProvider with `export function`, so there is no default, But I am curious about the error, why Module not found.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, It because publish in the folder `dist`, and the `pakcage.json` should be

```
  "main": "cjs/index.js",
  "module": "esm/index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
```

without start with "dist/***", so the module can't resolve!